# Could have + until

Tags: sentence-construction

I am not entirely sure if the following sentence makes sense:

> They had to [...], which could have possibly led to ostracization within their own communities until the group gained enough power.

I am not exactly sure if the "until the group [of they] gained enough power" makes sense grammatically.

Comment: Makes perfect sense to me (American, college-educated, no other particular qualifications to say so). It does make me wonder what they had to do...

Comment: Haha, thanks. I am not a native speaker, so sometimes I just confuse myself, to be honest.

Comment: Note that the until-clause does not depend specifically on the 'could have' here. It looks like it depends more on the word 'ostracization': "The group faced ostracization until they gained more power." (I'm not happy with this analysis, but I just wanted to point out that the 'could have' is not really relevant.)

Comment: @legatrix yeah I see it more clearly now thanks!